# Java send mail in secure environment (PCI-DSS)

Tags: java, security, encryption, jakarta-mail, pci-compliance

I am on the verge of being banned to ask questions, but I really need some light on the issue I face now.

I've written code which generates reports in a secure (PCI-DSS) environment and performs the following post generation:

1. Zip reports,
2. Email, &
3. SFTP to banks / internal.

Point 2: Email

I've used Spring's wrapper, the **JavaMailSender**, with the below configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class EmailConfigurations {

  @Autowired
  Environment env;

  @Bean
  public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setHost(env.getProperty("spring.mail.host"));
    mailSender.setPort(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("spring.mail.port")));

    mailSender.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.mail.username"));
    mailSender.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.mail.password"));

    Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");

    return mailSender;
  }

}
```

I've written basic mail sending service, which uses the above configured bean to send out mail:

```
package org.something.not.working;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.innoviti.emi.file.model.EmailModel;
import com.innoviti.emi.file.service.IEmailService;
import com.innoviti.emi.file.utility.Properties;

@Service
public class EmailServiceImpl implements IEmailService {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailServiceImpl.class);

  @Autowired
  public JavaMailSender emailSender;

  @Autowired
  Properties properties;

  @Override
  public void sendMessageWithAttachment(EmailModel model, List<Path> pathToAttachment)
      throws MessagingException, IOException {
    MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
    message.addRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO,
        InternetAddress.parse(toRecipients(model.getTo())));
    message.setSubject(model.getSubject());
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(model.getFrom()));

    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setText(model.getText());

    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    if (pathToAttachment != null && !pathToAttachment.isEmpty()) {
      for (Path filePath : pathToAttachment) {
        MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        try {
          attachPart.attachFile(filePath.toFile().getCanonicalPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
          LOG.error("IO error while attaching file to mail.", e);
          throw e;
        }
        multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
      }
    }
    message.setContent(multipart);
    emailSender.send(message);
    LOG.info("Request of email completed, {}", "for daily Emi Off Us files & SBI INCMS file.");
  }

  private String toRecipients(String[] tos) {
    if (tos == null || tos.length == 0)
      return null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < tos.length; i++) {
      sb.append(tos[i]).append(",");
    }
    return sb.toString().substring(0, sb.length() - 1);
  }

  @Override
  public void triggerMail(EmailModel model, Path attachment)
      throws MessagingException, IOException {
    List<Path> allAttachments = new ArrayList<>();
    if (attachment != null) {
      allAttachments.add(attachment);
    }
    this.sendMessageWithAttachment(model, allAttachments);
  }
}
```

All **this worked well in dev, as well as the test** environment ***UNLESS*** it was moved to secure (PCI-DSS) environment.

Here is the error I get:

```
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2018-08-23 06:40:00.993 ERROR 27545 [taskScheduler-7] --- c.i.emi.file.scheduler.EmailScheduler    : Line No. 47 : Error while fetching all files root path.
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Default SSLContext not available. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Default SSLContext not available
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:432)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:345)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)
        at org.something.which.has.email.impl.EmailServiceImpl.sendMessageWithAttachment(EmailServiceImpl.java:68)
        at org.something.which.has.scheduler.EmailScheduler.shootEmail(EmailScheduler.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2064)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:724)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:501)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:421)
        ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Default SSLContext not available
        at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(SSLSocketFactory.java:248)
        at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:270)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:524)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2059)
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Default SSLContext not available
        at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:96)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:122)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:519)
        ... 23 common frames omitted
```

I have sincerely no clue as to what needs to be done.

For reproducing it, in my local dev, I changed the following in JAVA_HOME which is: **...jdk/jre/library/security/java.security**

*1. Algorithm restrictions for certification path (CertPath) processing:*

> // Example:
>    // jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, DSA, RSA keySize < 2048
>
> ```
> (added this) **jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, DSA, SSLv3, RSA keySize < 3096**
> ```
>
> // jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, SHA1 jdkCA & usage TLSServer, 
>    //    RSA keySize < 1024, DSA keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224

*2. Algorithm restrictions for signed JAR files:*

> //   jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024, DSA keySize < 1024
>
> ```
> (added this)  **jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RC4, SSLv3, RSA keySize < 3096, DSA keySize < 3096**
> ```

*3. Algorithm restrictions for Secure Socket Layer/Transport Layer Security 
    (SSL/TLS) processing:*

> ```
> (added this)  **jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=MD5, RC4, SSLv3, DSA, RSA keySize < 3096**
> ```
>
> //  jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize <
>   1024, \
>       EC keySize < 224, DES40_CBC, RC4_40

- Why ? To have something similar to the secured environment.
- Then ? The error is what I get as I have posted the stack trace.
- Now ? I am not sure. No clue.

Should I somehow ensure that the **SMTP** I use (*gmail*) should understand this environment ? **If yes, then how** ?

Should the **Mime type** be something like `application/x-pkcs7-mime`

Please let me know if anyone has any idea !

Java version - "**1.8.0_162**"

Comment: Please tell us the Java version you use, because the default TLS versions are [differs in each release](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/diagnosing-tls,-ssl,-and-https). If you have disabled the algos with smaller keysize, I would be curious whether you have installed the JCE extension or not too. You can [use the SunJSSE has a built-in debug facility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) to get better information what can be the problem.

Comment: And please don't forget to set [timeouts](https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/spring-boot/how-to-send-spring-boot-mail-example.html) for email sender.

Comment: @m4gic I will search about the JCE extention. I had no idea about it. I did download the [JCE unlimited strength policy jars](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html)

Comment: Please let me know about the JCE extention, in  case I am missing something very important here.

Comment: 8u161 up (and 9 up) already has the 'unlimited' policy enabled; see the release notes. Plus nothing in this error is related to 256-bitness. Unable to create SSLContext suggests your provider list is screwed up: make sure you haven't removed or altered `com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider` (JSSE) in the provider list in `JRE/lib/security/java.security` and that your code hasn't changed it in memory; try `for(Provider p : Security.getProviders()) System.out.println(p.getName())` or similar and look at it or post it.

Comment: Also: disabling RSA<3096 is a bad idea; few if any servers will meet that requirement. And finally I assume you know sending PAN/CHD in clear by email is prohibited, even if _one_ email link is TLS, because you can't ensure other links are; you need to encrypt the _data_ in the body end-to-end. Of course if you're not sending PAN/CHD this doesn't apply.

Comment: Providers:
SUN,
SunRsaSign,
SunEC,
SunJSSE,
SunJCE,
SunJGSS,
SunSASL,
XMLDSig,
SunPCSC,
SunMSCAPI

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yes I understand sending PAN/CHD is not allowed.
So even a normal e mail. That too is not working here. And encrypting can be seen once a simple mail works.

Comment: I can encrypt the reports itself (zip it and then encrypt), attach it to the mail, and being able to send. But as of now, a simple mail is not going through.

I am occupied now (or forced) to find any other alternative for this, but ASAP I will be enabling the debug and check the logs.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a separate application that you can test on the FIPS environment that simply completes the handshake of the TLS connection and logs as much as possible. If it succeeds you will have a clear log, and if it doesn't then you known it's not specific to the mail config. Note that StackOverflow is for specific questions rather than debugging. As we cannot access your code or server SO cannot easily test anything (and problems with your rather specific config may not be of any use to anybody else). That said, I don't see any particularly wrong with this post, so I voted it up.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks. And yes, I will be debugging it end to end, as in my organization, if anyone has faced this issue, they blocked email comm, and used an alternative. I would try to get to the core of this.

Comment: With SunJSSE in the provider list, SSLContext Default should work; it might or might not have problems later doing the handshake, but the context itself should work. The only thing I can imagine is spring[boot] altering classloading, but I can't see why it would affect core JRE functionality and especially why it would differ between dev and prod. Sorry. Maybe testing outside the spring environment (if you can) will help.